# How to strip all attributes from an HTML td tag but rowspan in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, html-parsing

Using **python 3.3** I'm trying to make some regular expression substitutes unsuccessfully.

I want to strip all attributes of the `td` tags except the `rowspan` attribute (**example td's at the end**).

Using following command I can substitute successfully when `rowspan` exists:

```
re.sub('(<td)[^>]*([\\s]rowspan[\\s]*=[\\s]*[0-9]*)[^>]*(>)', handle_td, file_contents)
```

where `handle_td` is:

```
def handle_td(matchobj):
    new_td = ''
    for curr_group in matchobj.groups(''):
        if curr_group != '':
            new_td += curr_group
    return new_td
```

But I want also to take care of the rest of the `td` 's. This I didn't manage.

If I add `?` after the second group it changes td tag to  and does not keep the `rowspan` attribute.

**What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?**

**I don't mined running another command to handle the other `td` 's but I didn't manage...**

```
<td width=307 valign=top style='width:230.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-left:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
<td width=307 rowspan=4 style='width:230.3pt;border:solid windowtext 1.0pt; border-top:none;padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
<td width=307 valign=top style='width:230.3pt;border-top:none;border-left: none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'>
```

This should produce:

```
<td>
<td rowspan=4>
<td>
```

---

I managed this way (**if you have a better way feel free to add it**):

```
# Leave only specific attributes for td tags 
def filter_td_attributes(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1) == "rowspan":
        return matchobj.group(1) + '=' + matchobj.group(2)

# Loop the attributes of the td tags
def handle_td(matchobj):
    new_td = re.sub("([a-zA-Z]+)[\\s]*=[\\s]*([a-zA-Z0-9:;.\\-'\\s]*)([\\s]|>)", filter_td_attributes, matchobj.group(0))
    new_td = re.sub("[\\s]*$", '', new_td)
    new_td = new_td + ">" # close the td tag
    return new_td

file_contents = re.sub('[\\s]*</p>[\\s]*</td>', '</td>', file_contents)
```

Comment: Dont parse html/xml with regex.  Use a parser, it will be *so* much easier.

Comment: obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1350899

Comment: Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: I understand what you say but it's an over kill for what I need... I'm not doing a whole parsing just striping some very specific things.

Comment: Parsers were written for this?

Comment: @peterretief, I don't think so...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the `[^>]*` part of the code non-greedy when the rowspan code is optional: make it `[^>]*?`.  All together it becomes:

```
'(<td)[^>]*?([\\s]rowspan[\\s]*=[\\s]*[0-9]*)?[^>]*(>)'
```

The greedy version (`[^>]*`) means "give me as many non ">" characters as possible, but I will accept zero".

The non-greedy version (`[^>]*?`) means "give me the least number of non ">" characters as possible while still making the whole regex match"

Comment: Hey, at least you got something that works, that is the most important thing.  I've also noticed some "extra" stuff that are not really needed: the square brackets around the `\\s` values do nothing, and the parens around the `<td` and `>` are not really needed either -- you generally don't need to dynamically capture static text (and you aren't treating a group of characters as one entity like `(<td)*`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the brackets are for grouping so I can use the content of that group in the code.